# how to test bot detection

Tags: untagged

i want to test `cloudflare` bot detection in the site I'm working with after solving it once it never showed again how can i force it to show again

notes:

1. I'm using `puppeteer` for Web scraping i tried to use it as a bot browser but it didn't trigger the bot detection
2. I want just the `cloudflare` bot dectection page i don't mind if it is a demo or a real web site